# xcode objective c missing @end on NSObject

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsobject

I've been racking my brains for the past 2 hours regarding this issue and I couldn't find any solution through searching or by removing the imported files of my CustomTableCell.

Here's my class (.h)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MatchTableCell : UITableViewCell{

}

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *matchId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *fighter1Name;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *fighter2Name;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *status;


@end
```

This is what's popping up:

> Missing '@end'              .. this is popping up on the @interface line
>   Expected Identifier or '('  .. this highlights the first property

Thoughts?

EDIT: Solution. Apparently I can't post this as an answer even though that's how I solved the issue. Anyway, just in case it helps anyone, check the imports of the ViewControllers (or objects) that imports the file getting the error

*Well, that was very tedious. Found a ViewController that is imported by a second viewcontroller, this second viewcontroller imports this NSObject. The first viewcontroller, for some reason got changed from UITableViewController to UIViewController. Thanks to @rob-mayoff for the idea*

Comment: Clear the project and relaunch the xCode.

Comment: This piece of code looks fine, the error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Show us your imports as well.

Comment: last time I got this error I declared an enumeration wrong in my imports. Something like a `,` after the last entry or something similar.

Comment: Check the contents of the file(s) that are `#import`ed above where this one is `#import`ed.

Answer (score 18):

You are missing the `@end` directive at the end of one of your other `.h` files.  Go through the `.h` files in your project one by one.  For each one that has an `@interface` or `@protocol` section, make sure the section is terminated with an `@end` directive.

Comment: Well, that was very tedious. Found a ViewController that is imported by a second viewcontroller, this second viewcontroller imports this NSObject. The first viewcontroller, for some reason got changed from UITableViewController to UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Also to mention that start with checking the recently added files. XCODE starts to show this error any where but doesn't indicate which file is missing the combination of @interface and @end. One of the file will have it missing.